# Specialize member function for partially specialized class

Tags: c++, templates, specialization

I'm writing a class that holds fundamental types and call basic operators for scalar types.

```
template<typename _Ty>
class Fundamental {
    using DataType = _Ty;
public:        
    Fundamental(const DataType& value): value(value) {}
    operator DataType() { return value; }
    
    template<typename _Ty2>
    void operator+=(_Ty2 value) { this->value += value; }

    DataType value;
}
```

I made `operator+=` a template so it can take any value rather than just DataType. Eventually allowing me to add `float` with `int`, `char` with `int` and so on!

Pointer is not a fundamental type in C++ but it I need to implement it too. Pointer type however should only be added and subtracted with a integer (That's what I need). So, to do that I thought of partially specializing my class for pointer and fully specialize `operator+=` to take `int` like

```
template<>
template<typename _Ty>
void Fundamental<_Ty*>::operator+=(int value) { this->value += value; }
```

This however doesn't work and compiler complains

```
Fundamental<_Ty*>::operator +=': unable to match function definition to an existing declaration
```

**How do I make the operator accept only integer for pointers?**

I tried using-declaration

```
template<typename T>
using Param = typename std::conditional<std::is_pointer<DataType>::value, int, T>::type;

template<typename _Ty>
void operator+=(Param<_Ty> value) { this->value += value; }
```

Error occurs saying '... does not define this operator ...'.

Comment: Identifiers starting with an underscore followed by an uppercase letter are reserved in all contexts. You are not allowed to declare them or define them as macros.

Comment: @user17732522 My bad! But I'm quite used to this approach which will take time to get hands off. Thanks.

Comment: Default (ISO C++14 Standard)

Comment: What exactly is your goal? Do you just want it to fail with a (nicer) error message if someone tries to add the class with something else than an integer? Or do you need a SFINAE-friendly way to restrict the operator overload for wrong types?

Comment: I don't think your specialization work though (even if it compile). you only specilize for `<T*,int>`, so `<T*,U>` would still use the default one.

Comment: @user17732522 Friendly way to prevent this form happening.

Comment: If you just want an error if someone tries to use wrong types, you don't really have to do anything. The original already works for pointer and integer and fails for e.g. pointer and pointer. You could add a `static_assert` inside the operator's body to assert that the types match to exclude e.g. operator overloads. If you need SFINAE-friendlieness, before C++20, you can use SFINAE via e.g. `std::enable_if` to enforce the type match in the primary template or alternatively you can add a partial specialization of the _whole_ class for pointers (which is usually more work).

Answer (score 0):

Template specialization does not remove the default template, it just makes one "special".

Now you could probably make the default one invalid using some SFINAE but the right approach is to simply leave out the template from your pointer specialization and use a plain, int-only method.

```
template<class T>
class Fundamental<T*> {
   //...
   // not a template
   void operator += (int x) { ... }
};
```